# How to validate the date received in the response in Karate BDD

Tags: date, karate

I have two fields in the response having two parameters in response.
{
date1: "18-12-2018",
date2: "23-11-2018"
}

i want to test id date1 is less than today's date
and date2 is less than some otherdate in request param.
I dont know how this i can perform in karate schema validation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to parse the string date into a java date / long

```
* def toTime =
    """
    function(s) {
      var SimpleDateFormat = Java.type('java.text.SimpleDateFormat');
      var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
      return sdf.parse(s).time           
    }
    """ 
* def other = "20-11-2018"
* def today = new java.util.Date().time
* def response = { date1: "18-12-2018", date2: "23-11-2018" }
* assert today > toTime(response.date1)
* assert toTime(other) < toTime(response.date2)
```

EDIT: using `java.util.Date` is [not recommended any more](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html), please refer to this example that uses the modern `java.time` and `LocalDate` API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74729997/143475

Comment: hi thanks for the response but i need to compare date1 with current date and date2 with some request input date, sorry to add the date date1 in the response has timestamp which i want to ignore

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs. I have one more question if i have this date field is part of a array like a: [{ date1: "18-12-2018", date2: "23-11-2018" },{ date1: "18-12-2018", date2: "23-11-2018" },{ date1: "18-12-2018", date2: "23-11-2018" }]. i want to perform * assert each a[*].date1 <today but its not working.. i know this question is not part of the orinial one, but if you can help, it saves my lots of time

Comment: i tried  assert toTime(a[0].date1) < today which works, but i want to test each date1 of array

Comment: Then match each response.Data.a contains { "date1": "#? toTime(_) < today" } which is not working

Comment: @KarateCoder open a new question if needed please

Comment: perter, i will open a new question, i am asking it here due to  toTime(_) < today condition

Comment: i have added one more question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132772/how-to-test-each-date-field-in-the-array-response-using-karate

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to Peter Thomas's answer.  Here is how I externalized it into a callable .feature file:

```
@ignore
Feature: Reusable function to capture info about the date

  # Example:
  # * def dateResponse = call read('classpath:features/test_getdate.feature')
  # * def todaysDate = dateResponse.today
  # * def lastYearDate = dateResponse.oneYearAgo

  Background: Setup
    * def pattern = 'MM/dd/yyyy'
    * def getDate =
      """
      function() {
        var SimpleDateFormat = Java.type('java.text.SimpleDateFormat');
        var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        var date = new java.util.Date();
        return sdf.format(date);
      } 
      """

  Scenario: Capture todays date
    * def today = getDate()
    * karate.log("Today's date is: " + today )

  Scenario: Capture a year old date
    * def today = getDate()
    * def getSubtractedYear =
      """
      function(s) {
        var DateTimeFormatter = Java.type("java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter");
        var LocalDate = Java.type("java.time.LocalDate");
        var ChronoUnit = Java.type("java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit");
        var dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
        try {
          var adj = LocalDate.parse(today, dtf).minusMonths(12);
          return dtf.format(adj);
        } catch(e) {
          karate.log('*** date parse error: ', s);
        }
      } 
      """
    * def oneYearAgo = getSubtractedYear()
    * karate.log("One year ago is: " + oneYearAgo)
```

Then I test it like so:

```
@mysuite
Feature: Get information about the date

  Background: Setup
    * def dateResponse = call read('classpath:features/test_getdate.feature')

  Scenario: Extract todays date
    * def todaysDate = dateResponse.today
    * karate.log("Captured todays date: " + todaysDate)

  Scenario: Extract last years date
    * def lastYearDate = dateResponse.oneYearAgo
    * karate.log("Captured last years date: " + lastYearDate)
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`, which you are already using in the other method, are so much better.

Comment: Sorry, I got the SimpleDateFormat example straight from Peter Thomas in his answer on this same thread.    The important thing here, for me, was to show a nice variation on the documented solution that shows that you can do different things here to accomplish the goal.

Comment: @djangofan thanks for throwing me under the bus ;) anyway - for those looking for an example using the Java `LocalDate` please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74729997/143475