# Karate- Need help to assert a single dimension array for date range

Tags: automation, karate

I am trying to assert the values inside a single dimensional array. I have tried using match but it looks like the date ranges cannot be asserted.

Below is the object array:

```
[
"2019-04-24T17:41:28",
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.975",
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.954",
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.93",
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.907",
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.886",
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.862",
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.84",
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.816",
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.792"
]
```

I am trying to assert each values between the following date ranges:

```
MinDate:2019-04-24T17:25:00.000000+00:00
MaxDate:2019-04-24T17:50:00.000000+00:00
```

I have tried the following but none works:

```
* match dateCreated == '#[]? _.value >= fromDate'
 * eval for(var i = 0; i < responseJson.response.data.TotalItemCount; i++) dateCreated.add(responseJson.response.data.Items[i].DateCreated)  karate.assert(dateCreated[i] >= fromDate)
```

Any hint/tip on how to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def dateToLong =
"""
function(s) {
  var SimpleDateFormat = Java.type('java.text.SimpleDateFormat');
  var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
  return sdf.parse(s).time;
} 
"""
* def min = dateToLong('2019-04-24T17:25:00.000')
* def max = dateToLong('2019-04-24T17:50:00.000')
* def isValid = function(x){ var temp = dateToLong(x); return temp >= min && temp <= max }

* def response =
"""
[
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.975",
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.954",
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.93",
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.907",
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.886",
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.862",
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.84",
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.816",
"2019-04-24T17:41:27.792"
]
"""
* match each response == '#? isValid(_)'
```

Please refer the docs if you have doubts about any of the keywords. I removed the first date in the list because it was not consistent, but you have enough info to handle it if needed - you may need some conditional logic somewhere.

Also see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54114432/143475

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52892797/143475

Comment: Thanks Peter!. This works. I was thinking in a very different direction. Like asserting inside a custom function with a 'for' loop. But this works just perfect.

Comment: @rahulqelfo my advice is never use JS loops in karate ever, it leads to messy code. besides `match each` get used to map, filter and forEach: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms