# Karate | How to subtract two dates in karate

Tags: javascript, java, cucumber, karate

```
Scenario: Testing date
      Given url 
      When method get
      Then status 200
      And def releaseDate = response.meta.event.releaseDate
      And print "Release Data is: ", releaseDate
      * def today =
        """
        function() {
          var SimpleDateFormat = Java.type('java.text.SimpleDateFormat');
          var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat('MMM dd, yyyy');
          return sdf.format(new java.util.Date());
        }
        """
      * print today()
      * def today = today()
      * eval diff = today- releaseDate
      And print "Difference is: ", diff
      And assert diff >= 14
```

```
* def datediff =
        """
        function(first, second) {
        return Math.round((second - first) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        }
        """
      * eval diff = datediff(today, releaseDate)
```

Getting the following

16:16:02.894 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] Release Data is:  Aug 15, 2002
16:16:02.965 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] Dec 08, 2022
16:16:02.974 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] Today's date is:  Dec 08, 2022
16:16:03.044 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] Difference is:  NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that should answer all your questions. There can be improvements, but I leave that as a homework for you.

```
* def toDate =
"""
function(date) {
  var Formatter = Java.type("java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter");
  var LocalDate = Java.type("java.time.LocalDate");  
  var dtf = Formatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
  return LocalDate.parse(date, dtf);
}
"""

* def dateMinus =
"""
function(dateString, days) {
    var date = toDate(dateString);
    return date.minusDays(days);
}
"""

* def formatDate =
"""
function(date) {
  var Formatter = Java.type("java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter");
  var LocalDate = Java.type("java.time.LocalDate");  
  var dtf = Formatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
  return dtf.format(date);
}
"""

* def beforeDate = '2022-12-08'
* def afterDate = dateMinus(beforeDate, 5)
* def afterDateString = formatDate(afterDate)
* match afterDateString == '2022-12-03'
```

If you have more questions please refer to the Java [`LocalDate`](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) API.