# How to get around long integer error when doing value comparison

Tags: karate

I have never come across this error before. From research it seems that it can happen when integers are too large and the result ends up in a notation of sorts.

My setup:

```
The inputs are the following two sets of json objects:

* def actual = {
  "Name": "Roger",
  "Number": 567553218,
  "Date": "2022-12-09"}
* def expected = {
  "Name": "Roger",
  "Number": 567553218,
  "Date": "2022-12-09"}

The method I am using for the above:
            
            function(actual, expected) {
                var temp = [];
                var now = new Date();
                var dateNow = new Date(now.getTime() + now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

                for (key in actual) {
                    if (typeof actual[key] === 'number') {
                        actual[key] = new java.math.BigDecimal(actual[key]);
                    }
                    var matchCheck = false;
                    var dateActual = Date.parse(actual[key]);
                    if (isNaN(dateActual) || !(isNaN(actual[key]))) {
                        if (expected.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                            var tempMatch = karate.match(actual[key],expected[key]);
                            matchCheck = tempMatch.pass;
                        }
                        else {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
```

When the method executes, the following error is displayed:

`org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow`

The error is likely happening on the "567553218" under the Number key. As you can see, I tried to use BigDecimal Java method as highlighted in Karate documentation. However, that does not work. I may have made a mistake in the JavaScript, I am still a big newbie in it. Please let me know if that is the case.

Comment: I pass on this question. please use the Java `LocalDate` for conversions. if that doesn't work, raise a bug as this is important to fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74729997/143475 - I do not recommend using the JS `Date` or things like `isNan()` at all

Comment: by the way, the reason I pass on this question because it is not simple enough, next time please try to simulate in just 3 or 4 lines