# How to fix date in the following Karate code?

Tags: karate

I have the following line of code in karate-config.js file

```
var curDate = new Date();
karate.log("curDate", curDate);
```

its printing log as below:

> curDate {
> }

any idea why this would happen. It used to work before 1.0 but after updating to latest version 1.3, it started failing

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in the `karate.log()` function. You can do this instead:

```
karate.log("curDate", curDate.toString());
```

Personally I recommend using the JVM Date classes, for e.g: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74729997/143475

Contributions to the code base are welcome.